# Flow seems stuck parsing files on startup

Tags: flowtype

I use flow for a large JS project of mine. It used to work fine, showing errors in vim. But something happened in the last few months where it stopped reporting any errors (but still compiling fine using babel). When I started investigating, the issue seems to be that the flow server never finishes starting, for whatever reason. I have updated my flow-bin and flow-typed (`sudo npm install -g flow-bin && sudo npm install -f flow-typed`). When I attempt to start flow, I see the following message indefinitely (as number of parsed files keeps climbing to ridiculously high numbers):

```
Please wait. Server is initializing (parsed files 132568): /
```

It seems that both vim and atom editors I tried keep running into the same exact issue (vim silently, and atom actually shows a spinner claiming that flow is initializing. This is what my `.flowconfig` looks like:

```
[ignore]
.*\.git/.*
.*/public/*
.*/scripts/*
.*/dist/*
.*/cypress/*
.*/uploads/*

[untyped]
.*/node_modules/*
.*/lib/*

[libs]
flow-typed

[lints]
sketchy-null=warn

[options]
suppress_comment= \\(.\\|\n\\)*\\@flow-ignore
```

Currently installed versions:

```
❯❯❯ flow --version
Flow, a static type checker for JavaScript, version 0.116.1
❯❯❯ flow-typed --version
3.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `[options]` section in `.flowconfig` with:

```
sharedmemory.hash_table_pow=21
```